# How to Display Featured Image Title and ALT Attribute

Tags: images

hi i am try this code for display featured image after first paragraph and display image title and alt attribute

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
   $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
   $img = '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="" title=""/>';
   $content = preg_replace('#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1'.$img, $content, 1);
   return $content;
});
```

featured image display correctly but title and alt attribute not show, please tell me anyone whats a problem in this code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe following function is what you are looking for.
The important part you are looking for in the code is the line which holds the [pathinfo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php),
which is php and not WordPress specific.

There are probably several other options but as nobody responded till now I think that this function will help you out till another *(maybe better)* answer is added by someone else.

> You could make a backup of the functions.php (found in the theme folder) before you add this function to it.

I have tested it in a sandbox with the WP version 4.9.6 and it should work flawless.

```
/**
 * Add content on Alt/Title tags
 * 
 * @link    https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/306250
 * @version Wordpress V4.9.6 
 * 
 * Source:
 * @see     https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url
 * @see     https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
 * @see     https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
 * 
 * @param   [type] $content [description]
 * @return  [type]          [description]
 */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_filename_on_img_tags' );
function add_filename_on_img_tags( $content )
{
    // get featured image
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
    // get filename
    $filename = pathinfo( $arr['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME );
    // add content on ALT/TITLE tags
    $img = '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="' . $filename . '" title="' . $filename . '"/>';
    // add image after first paragraph
    $content = preg_replace( '#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1' . $img, $content, 1 );

    return $content;

} // end function
```

In the docblock you find links with information for code as used in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing in the code to display those values, try:

```
$img = '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"/>';
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but this code retrieve post title in image title and alt attribute, but i want to show image name in title and alt attribute

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as well.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'title' => get_the_title(get_post_thumbnail_id()),'alt' => get_the_post_thumbnail_caption() ) );
```